# CXF Soap Webservices input and output messages as part of ComplexType

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm using CXF for my webservices.
I have bean

```
public class Document {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Date createdDate;
//....getters/setters
}
```

I have a webmethod interface

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "SaveDocument")
Document saveDocument(@WebParam(name = "document") Document document);
```

Is it somehow possible, that input message would be without ID and createdDate? Or should I make two 2 beans. One for input and another for response?
Like

```
public class DocumentIn {
    private String name;
    private String description;
//....getters/setters
}
```

and

```
public class DocumentOut {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Date createdDate;
//....getters/setters
}
```

and webmethod

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "SaveDocument")
DocumentOut saveDocument(@WebParam(name = "document") DocumentIn document);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same type as parameter and result. Just primitive types are ever required. If you use

```
Integer id
```

instead of int, than it is possible to let it null that means omit the 'id' element in your SOAP XML.

Also if the document is same and you just add 'id' and 'createdDate' on the server side, you can use INOUT parameter as well, see http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/webservice-holder/